# JavaScript syntax & indentation in Vim

Tags: javascript, vim

I know this has been asked before, but I'm having trouble getting JavaScript indentation to work properly in Vim.

I tried installing this plugin:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3081

And I get this behaviour:

```
if (x == 1) {
alert("nice");
}
```

This is my vimrc:

```
syntax on
set background=light
colorscheme solarized
set tabstop=4
filetype plugin indent on
let g:solarized_termcolors=16
```

I also tried it with this plugin:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1840

But that gives me this:

```
if (x == 1) {
        alert("nice");
}
```

i.e., two tabs, where I only want it to indent by a single tab.

Anyone have any ideas what to do here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried this in your .vimrc

```
set smarttab
set cindent
```

edit also the JavaScript "plugin" I use for VIM is [javascript.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1491) which replaces the default VIM javascript syntax file.

No matter what plugins you use, indenting in VIM is usually pretty bad, and is a common complaint with VIM users, especially with JavaScript. There is no perfect solution, which is strange considering the powerful extensibility of VIM.

Comment: I work in Vim all day on JavaScript and don't seem to have any real issues with Javascript indenting. Have a look at my Vim dotfiles on Github --> [https://github.com/shanestillwell/dotvim](https://github.com/shanestillwell/dotvim)

Comment: Although this is marked as the right answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/9896760/209864 worked better for me.

Comment: @ShaneStillwell those per-language Autocmds are right to the point.

Answer (score 18):

Vim wiki explains how to setup filetype-specific indentation, and it's pretty straight-forward: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Indenting_source_code#Different_settings_for_different_file_types

The simplest way is to put `autocmd FileType` instructions in your `.vimrc` file. You can specify indentation for each file type separately:

```
autocmd FileType javascript setlocal shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2
autocmd FileType html       setlocal shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2
autocmd FileType python     setlocal shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4 expandtab
```

or set default indentation for all file types, and override it for the specific ones:

```
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4

autocmd FileType javascript setlocal shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2                                                   
autocmd FileType html setlocal shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2
```

Comment: The problem for me is that JavaScript in HTML is broken. HTML correctly indents with 4 spaces, but the JavaScript indents with 16 spaces and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 7):

I came here from google and was unsatisfied with Yi Zhao's indent file as suggested above. Still wasn't catching some nested functions of mine.

I asked around on twitter and was suggested https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript - with which I am far happier.

HTH,

Comment: Thanks a lot! You're right... the [pangloss](https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript) one you suggested is better than the [Yi Zhao](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1491) and [jelera](https://github.com/jelera/vim-javascript-syntax) alternatives.